# Returning Failure if File does not exist

Tags: powershell

I am running the below script in SQL Server Agent.

All the subsequent steps in job are dependent upon this step. This is pretty simple Looking for a file and exits with failure if file is not found.

```
  $file = "C:\\Data\\FileDrop\\.done"
  $CheckFile = Test-Path -Path $file

  if (!($CheckFile))  {exit 1 }
```

However when the agent job runs, it says the step failed because file not found and existing with code 0 - success.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is but if you don't need to store the result of test-path then you can just use if(!t(test-path -path $file)). You can also use if((test-path -path $file) -eq $false))

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue is, it exits with code=0 success. How do I fail this if file is not found?

Comment: Don't escape backslashes in PowerShell string literals: `\ ` has no special meaning (`\`` is PowerShell's escape character), so it doesn't need escaping. That said, in file paths double backslashes are usually benign (treated the same as a single backslash). Is the file the job reports as not found really `C:\Data\FileDrop\.done`? In your invocation scenario, is _any_ exit code from your PowerShell script reflected in the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the return value / error code of the job has anything to do with whatever value the script returns.

If you want to fail with an error message, try this:

```
# make sure to stop on errors
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$path = 'C:\Data\FileDrop\.done'
# check for file explicitly (in case a directory with that name exists)
if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($path)) {
    # throwing an exception will abort the job
    throw (New-Object System.IO.FileNotFoundException("File not found: $path", $path))
}
# anything after this will not be executed on error...
```

This should fail the job entirely and show the error message in the job's history.

Comment: If the OP doesn't actually care about the setting the exit code and just wants to ensure that the job fails in this condition then I think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
if(!(Test-Path "C:\Data\FileDrop\.done")){
    return 1
}
else {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be a great answer because I have not found the documentation that explains this but the use of Exit followed by a number seems to not have any effect on the exit code.

The following example works, with the general idea taken from a [blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/soever/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script).
First create a test script like the following:

```
$host.SetShouldExit(12345)
exit
```

Next call this script from the Powershell command line as in the following example:

```
$command = "C:\YourTestScriptPathAndName.ps1"
Powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command $command
```

The script will run and exit, and we can then check the exit code from the Powershell prompt by writing out the contents of $LASTEXISTCODE

```
$LASTEXITCODE
```

In this case $LASTEXISTCODE would contain 12345.

In the case of using this with Test-Path it would look like this:

```
#using a path that does not exist
if(Test-Path -Path 'C:\nope'){
   $host.SetShouldExit(1234)
}
else{
   $host.SetShouldExit(2222)
}
```

This sets the exit code to 2222 when invoked from the command line, but when I invoke that test script from another script instead of from the command line the $LASTEXITCODE variable is set to 0 still.